# How to remove empty space on the left of jsTree contextMenu

Tags: asp.net-mvc, contextmenu, jstree

I'm using jsTree plugin in my ASP.NET MVC application and have a strange issue. I've attached contextMenu plugin, but its items have a strange empty space on the left, like in the image below:

[image]

My code is followed:

```
$(function () {
    $("#competence-areas-tree").jstree({
        core: {
            data: {
                cache: false,
                url: '@Url.Action("GetTreeData", "CompetenceArea")'
            },
            multiple: false
        },
        types: {
            competenceArea: {
                icon: "@Url.Stylesheet("/jstree-3.0.0b/competenceArea.png")"
            }
        },
        contextmenu: {
            items: function ($node) {
                return {
                    createItem: {
                        separator_before: false,
                        separator_after: false,
                        label: "Создать",
                        submenu: {
                            create: {
                                separator_before: false,
                                separator_after: false,
                                label: "Создать на текущем уровне",
                                action: function() {
                                    Create($node.parent);
                                }
                            },
                            createChild: {
                                separator_before: false,
                                separator_after: false,
                                label: "Создать потомка",
                                action: function() {
                                    Create($node.id);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    editItem: {
                        separator_before: false,
                        separator_after: false,
                        label: "Редактировать",
                        action: function() {
                            Edit($node.id);
                        }
                    },
                    deleteItem: {
                        separator_before: false,
                        separator_after: false,
                        label: "Удалить",
                        action: function() {
                            Delete($node.id);
                        }
                    },
                    detailGraphItem: {
                        separator_before: false,
                        separator_after: false,
                        label: "Перейти к графу",
                        action: function() {
                            DetailGraph($node.id);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        plugins: ["types", "contextmenu", "themes"]
    }).on("changed.jstree", function(e, data) { 
        if (data.action === "select_node") {
            OnSelectingNode(data.node.original.id);
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I made a jsfiddle for the context menu you have provided but there isn't anything wrong with it. There is always a default space to the left with the context menu in the jstree but not to the extent that you're having. Here is the jsfiddle to see if that can help:

http://jsfiddle.net/3q9Ma/529/

```
    $(function () {
    var data = [
       { "id" : "ajson1", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Simple root node" },
       { "id" : "ajson2", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Root node 2" },
       { "id" : "ajson3", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 1" },
       { "id" : "ajson4", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 2" },
    ];
    $("#jstree").jstree({
     "core" : {
       "check_callback" : true,

        "data": data
     },
    "plugins" : [ "contextmenu",  "dnd"],

        contextmenu: {
            items: function ($node) {
                return {
                    createItem: {
                        separator_before: false,
                        separator_after: false,
                        label: "Создать",
                        submenu: {
                            create: {
                                separator_before: false,
                                separator_after: false,
                                label: "Создать на текущем уровне",
                                action: function() {
                                    Create($node.parent);
                                }
                            },
                            createChild: {
                                separator_before: false,
                                separator_after: false,
                                label: "Создать потомка",
                                action: function() {
                                    Create($node.id);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    editItem: {
                        separator_before: false,
                        separator_after: false,
                        label: "Редактировать",
                        action: function() {
                            Edit($node.id);
                        }
                    },
                    deleteItem: {
                        separator_before: false,
                        separator_after: false,
                        label: "Удалить",
                        action: function() {
                            Delete($node.id);
                        }
                    },
                    detailGraphItem: {
                        separator_before: false,
                        separator_after: false,
                        label: "Перейти к графу",
                        action: function() {
                            DetailGraph($node.id);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

  }).on('create_node.jstree', function(e, data) {
    console.log('saved');
});
$("#sam").on("click",function() {
     $('#jstree').jstree().create_node('#' ,  { "id" : "ajson5", "text" : "newly added" }, "last", function(){
    alert("done");
 });
});
});
```

Comment: I guess it happens because of ASP.NET MVC, I'll dig it later, maybe will find the issue. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: No problem. Let me know how it goes

Comment: I found the issue. The problem was that I had a css rule `text-align: center` for `li` elements in my common css file.